# Issue trying to load image from json path in CRA app

Tags: json, reactjs, image, frontend, create-react-app

I'm unable to load images from `src/assets/image` in my CRA app. I'm trying to avoid putting these images in my public folder but for some reason that seems to be the only way they will be displayed.

I have a json file `homepageinfo.ts` with a path

```
export const homepageinfo: homepageinfoType = {
  ...
  hero_portrait: "testimg.jpg",
};
```

A util function file `dataClient` to import json files with the function getHomePageInfo.

```
export const getHomePageInfo = () => {
  return homepageinfo;
};
```

and another file `HomeTitle.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Header, Image, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { getHomePageInfo } from "utils/dataClient";

export const HomeTitle = () => {
  let homepageinfo = getHomePageInfo();

  return (
    <Grid columns={2}>
      ...
      <Grid.Column
        only="tablet computer"
        verticalAlign="bottom"
        textAlign="right"
      >
        {console.log(require("assets/image/" + homepageinfo.hero_portrait))}
        <Image as="img"
          className="img_portrait"
          spaced={"left"}
          src={require("assets/image/" + homepageinfo.hero_portrait)}
        />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

The console.log is able to return a value for assets/image/homepageinfo.hero_portrait however it still appears blank in the actual Image component.

[image: Image of a blank component and a console output from Firefox]

If I move the image to the public folder it can display but I do not want to have to put these images inside of the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `default` from result returned by `require()`.

This is usually handled for you when `import` statement [is used](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) instead of `require()`

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Header, Image, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { getHomePageInfo } from "utils/dataClient";

export const HomeTitle = () => {
  let homepageinfo = getHomePageInfo();
  let imageUrl;
  try {
    const res = require("assets/image/" + homepageinfo.hero_portrait);
    console.log(res);
    imageUrl = res.default;
  } catch () {
    imageUrl = ''; // file not found
  }

  return (
    <Grid columns={2}>
      ...
      <Grid.Column
        only="tablet computer"
        verticalAlign="bottom"
        textAlign="right"
      >
        <Image as="img"
          className="img_portrait"
          spaced={"left"}
          src={imageUrl}
        />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

**UPDATED**
require() may fail if the file is not found.

So I'd recommend using `import` as documentation [suggests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) like this:

`homepageinfo.ts`:

```
import testImg from './assets/image/testimg.jpg';

export const homepageinfo: homepageinfoType = {
  ...
  hero_portrait: testImg,
};
```

This way all images will be resolved to paths during build time and `homepageinfo.hero_portrait` will contain the resulting URL

Comment: Thank you, adding default works. It might not make much sense in this particular case but I wanted to figure out how to load it from a json file path like this because I have other components that will have to load from an array of paths and I was running into the same issue with those. In those cases I don't think importing every single path will be very friendly.